# Tree Shaking without Babel in webpack 4

Tags: reactjs, webpack, antd, tree-shaking

Can external modules like React or Antd be shaked (tree-shaking) without Babel in webpack 4?

Example React structure:
node_modules->react folder includes /cjs and /umd directorys.

Setup:
Project:
https://github.com/webpack/webpack/tree/master/examples/harmony-unused
Configuration
https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/
Typescript-Loader(Optional) https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader

src Files will be shaked, all includes node_modules like antd or react not.

Greets Richie

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the react and reactdom or any other packages using externals from all the packages and load once using script tag on your pages.

```
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
module.exports = {
externals: {
react: 'React',
'react-dom': 'ReactDOM'
},
entry:{},//entry files
output: {} // output path and files
plugins: [
new CopyWebpackPlugin([
{
from: path.join('src/Commons/Polyfills/Symbol.js'),
to: 'manifest.js'
},
{
from : path.join('node_modules/react/umd/react.production.min.js'),
to : 'react.js'
},
{
from : path.join('node_modules/react-dom/umd/react-dom.production.min.js'),
to : 'react-dom.js'
}
]),
]
};
```

Comment: thanks for your answer,

but with these way i added the complete react package to my build.
I understood Tree-Shaking remove all unused package from the build to reduce the sended file size to client.